# How to restore the raid superblock back to the disk

Tags: raid, restore, mdadm

The system was re-installed, I have taken the raid superblock. `mdadm --create` had overwritten the superblock.
I have the data in the system as it is not formatted. Now I want to restore the superblock and use `mdadm --restore` to recreate the RAID. How to restore the superblock back to individual raid disks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a difficult problem to solve by mdadm itself, it's just no one has contributed the code to do the work. Your options are outlined here:

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery

None of them easy.

You'll want to create a dd image of your disks if possible, which understandably is easier said than done because of the sheer volume of data.

In the future, you can back up your superblock and send it off box for later disaster recovery. Hope this helps.